# How to decide which thread will wait after calling wait function?

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java multi-threading, wait method can be called on any object. How do we know which object will wait?

E.g:

1. I created a thread and in run method of that thread declared obj.wait() where obj is some object used in that thread class. When we call thread.start method from main method which thread will wait?
2. In another scenario, instead of calling wait inside run method of thread if I call it from main like t.wait() where t is thread method instance, then which thread will wait()?

Is the first and second scenario the same?

3. Or instead of calling t.wait() from main if I call obj.wait() from main where obj is some object in main method, then which thread will wait?

Could someone explain this concept as there are n number of possible ways to call wait from different contexts and on different objects?

Answer (score 2):

The thread that calls `obj.wait()` is the thread that waits.

> ...if I call it from main like t.wait()...

The threat that calls `t.wait()` is the thread that waits.  The type of the object does not matter.  It does not matter whether the object is a thread or any other kind of object.  The thread that calls `wait()` is the thread that waits.

> Could some one explain this concept...?

The Java tutorial does a pretty good job of that:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

---

**Better still:**  Don't rush to use `wait()` and `notify()`.  They are low-level primitives that are meant to be used in a very specific way (as shown in the tutorial) for building higher-level synchronization objects.  But the Java library and third party libraries already provide high-quality implementations of most of the synchronization objects that you'll ever need.

If your goal is to solve some particular problem, then don't waste your time re-inventing the wheel.  OTOH, It's a fine thing to do if your goal is to learn how wheels are built!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `obj.wait()`, it's always the current thread (that is, the thread that's running the method that called `obj.wait()`) that's suspended. It will only* be resumed when another thread synchronizes on `obj`, then calls `object.notify()` or `object.notifyAll()`, and finally exits the synchronized block on `obj` and thus releases the lock on its monitor.

When that first thread is resumed, it will first re-acquire the lock on `obj`. (You may only call `obj.wait()` while synchronized on `obj`, or else it'll [throw an `IllegalMonitorStateException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--). That lock is released while the thread is waiting, and re-acquired before the thread wakes up.)

**Calling `wait()` on a Thread instance is not handled specially, you should not use it, because Thread uses it already.** In particular, `t.wait()` does not cause that thread to wait, but rather, causes the current thread to wait until someone else synchronizes on that Thread object and calls `notify()` or `notifyAll()` on it, as described above. The problem is that Thread uses these methods for its own purposes, such as for [Thread.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-int-). By calling these methods on an instance of Thread, you will effectively be trying to shout over its own messaging, which would probably cause problems. As Thread's documentation puts it:

> It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.

---

* Threads can also wake up all on their own, which is called a spurious wakeup; but this is quite rare, and though you should defend against it, you should never assume it will happen. In particular, since you presumably called `wait()` to suspend your thread until some condition is met (another thread sets some variable, etc), you should always surround the `wait()` call in a loop that checks whether that condition has been met.

Comment: Re, "Calling wait() on a Thread is not special."  The _mechanism_ is no different from calling `wait()` on any other class of object, but the OpenJDK implementation of `java.lang.Thread` uses `wait()` and `notify()` on `Thread` objects for its own purposes.  If you write code that calls `t.wait()` it potentially could steal a notification that was intended for some private method of the `Thread` class.